# What's the significance of the scene where the twins encounter a man burning a field in Goodnight Mommy?

Tags: analysis, goodnight-mommy

In *[Goodnight Mommy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodnight_Mommy)*, the scene where the twins encounter a man burning a field seems out of place to me. I'm not sure how it moved the plot or if it is of significance.

[image: screencap of scene described above]

Is there symbolism or significance in this scene? Or did it move the plot in a way that I may have missed?

Comment: It could be foreshadowing the ending.